# Get and change all Elements of certain type

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a chrome extension and need to get all elements of this type:
[image]

I tried this but could not change the css properties of all these elements:

```
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".titleCard-progress"); 
for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {   
    nodeList[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
```

How can I get all elements of type progress and class titleCard-progress?

Comment: the code you've written should work. You can make the selector more specific with `process.titleCard-progress`. But if the problem is that you're not changing all of them, that won't help.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: There's a simpler solution you might use: instead of `js` declare `css` file in content_scripts in manifest.json and use this CSS code in the file `.titleCard-progress { visibility:hidden !important }`

Comment: ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question."

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe it is becouse your script execute when those elements are not generated yet. Think in when your code is executed, and when the elements are generated, even if you execute your code after the elements are generated, after that there will be more elements that will be generated and your code will do nothing with them.

For those kind of actions to act over all the elements and all the future elements, I would recommend to insert some CSS styles that will act over all current and future elements.

Not sure if that is the issue actually.

Good luck.